# Reinstalled Android Studio not opening

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, android-studio-3.0

I was facing some issues with Android Studio so I decided to reinstall the Android Studio.

So what I did was to rename the old Android Studio folder and simple downloaded new Android Studio and unzipped the content with the same old folder name.

But This has caused the Android Studio to not open.  However if I bring back the old folder and rename it back to its original name it is opening with the issues which were previously being faced by me.

Can anyone guide me on how to open new Android Studio?

Comment: try to remove the android studio file from the appdata in user if you are using windows then uninstall and install

Comment: @vaibhavsharma Thanks for the answer. But will that remove all my preference and settings?

Comment: yes it will like a fresh start

Comment: @vaibhavsharma OK Will try and update soon. What about the Android SDK Even that has to be cleared or they can remain as is?

Comment: move your sdk from that folder and after installing paste there

Comment: @vaibhavsharma Tried this but it is of no use. Any other suggestion please

Comment: I have but this is not good format your windowa

Comment: @vaibhavsharma It was not possible for me to format my Windows as that contains A LOT of important files and documents. But However trying to install the older version of the Android Studio solved the issue. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing slightly older version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

But you may face the same issue once you upgrade the Android Studio.

I was able to resolve the same issue by refer to the solution provided in Android Developer Portal,

[Studio doesn't start after upgrade](https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#studio-config-directories)

If Studio doesn't start after an upgrade, the problem may be due to an invalid Android Studio configuration imported from a previous version of Android Studio or an incompatible plugin. As a workaround, try deleting (or renaming, for backup purposes) the directory below, depending on the Android Studio version and operating system, and start Android Studio again. This will reset Android Studio to its default state, with all third-party plugins removed.

For Android Studio 4.1 and later:

Windows: %APPDATA%\Google\AndroidStudio Example: C:\Users\your_user_name\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1

macOS: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1

Linux: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio Example: ~/.config/Google/AndroidStudio4.1 and ~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1